# C++ Destructor is not called

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-allocation

I've got three classes: Room, Door and World

```
#include <set>;

using namespace std;

class Door; // Forward declaration

class Room {
public:
    Door* door1;
    Door* door2;

    Room(){}

    ~Room() {
        delete door1;
        door1 = 0;
        delete door2;
        door2 = 0;
    }
};

class Door {
public:
    Room* roomA;
    Room* roomB;

    Door(Room* roomA, Room* roomB) {
        this->roomA = roomA;
        this->roomB = roomB;
        linkRooms(); // This sets up the Door-Pointers in the Rooms
                     // so they know about the new door.
    }    

    ~Door() {
        // Returns the room-owned pointer pointing at this door
        getMyRoomPointer(roomA) = 0;
        getMyRoomPointer(roomB) = 0;
    }    

    Door * & getMyRoomPointer(Room * const & room) {
        if (room->door1 == this) return room->door1;
        else return room->door2;
    }

    void linkRooms() {
        roomA->door1 = this;
        roomB->door2 = this;
    }

};

class World {
public:
    std::set<Room*> rooms;

    World() {
        // Set up two rooms and link them using a door
        Room* newRoom = new Room();
        rooms.insert(newRoom);
        Room* anotherNewRoom = new Room();
        rooms.insert(anotherNewRoom);

        new Door(newRoom, anotherNewRoom);
    }
    ~World() {
        // Iterate over the rooms and call delete on all of them
        for (std::set<Room*>::iterator it = rooms.begin(); it != rooms.end(); ++it) {
            delete *it;
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    World world;

    return 0;
}
```

When running main, the constructor fills the world with just two rooms and a door as a link between them. After main returns, world should be deleted and all the rooms and doors also should be taken care of.

The thing is, that my Door destructor is never called. So the Door pointers inside the rooms are not set to null and I get an error when the room "at the other side" tries to delete the same door.

When I just create an instance of Door, and than delete it right afterwards, I'm not facing any problems:

```
int main(){

    Room oneRoom;
    Room anotherRoom;

    Door* door = new Door(&oneRoom, &anotherRoom);
    delete door; // works just fine

    return 0;
}
```

Questions: **Why is the Door constructor not called? Is setting up Door like in the first example allowed?**

I know, that I'm double deleting my room's Door pointers, and that I could (and should) use SmartPointers. Right now I'm just wondering why I am facing that kind of behavior. I'm still new  to  C++, after all.

I did set up a runnable example now, that reproduces the error.

Comment: you should probably attach the code that _should_ delete the `Room`s  - otherwise we don't know what to diagnose ;) BTW, probably each `Door` will be deleted twice, since each `Room` has it's own pointers

Comment: [mcve], please. We can hardly analyse this without knowing how `getMyRoomPointer` works, for example.

Comment: You probably should use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: I added the function, sry for missing that, I tried to break it down as good as possible and just forgot about it

Comment: @MaXL130 the example still isn't complete or verifiable. It doesn't compile. Test the example with a compiler before posting.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am not sure if that is a good  way to prove that the destructor is not called, but if I place a breakpoint in there, it is never hit...

Comment: @molbdnilo It is not a typo, I also asked, if it is allowed to do it that way. I had the theory, that the references inside the rooms that are set up by the doors constructor would be enough to reference and delete it later on. I added the the linkRooms() function, just to clarify that.

Comment: AFAICT, this should work, unless the code you posted from the "world" class is all inside the constructor, in which case your declaration of `rooms` is hiding the member variable.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `door1= 0;` in the destructor is pointless. The object is going away, and nobody will ever see that instance of `door1` again.

Comment: @user2079303 I provided a working example, not very small, but due to the fact that I have no clue why it isn't working, I hope that is alright...

Comment: you can't delete what you have not new.

Comment: @Stargateur Would you mind giving me a bit more detail?

Comment: `getMyRoomPointer` is confusing as hell. It doesn't return a room pointer at all

Comment: Consider using `std::shared_ptr`, `std::enable_shared_from_this` and `std::weak_ptr` instead of manipulating raw pointers yourself. This sort of ownership manipulation is exactly what they were designed for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `delete` before `Door` has been defined. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined, and the destructor is not guaranteed to be called.

A quote from the standard (draft) [[expr.delete]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#5):

> 5. If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined.

Solution: If the destructor of the type is non-trivial (i.e. user defined, such as the `~Door`, then never delete such object until the type is complete). In this case, define `Door`, before the functions that call delete.

As a general rule, you can never call a member function unless the class type is complete. Unfortunately in the case of destructor, it may not always be possible for the compiler to catch the bug. PS. g++ does warn about your program: `warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]`

Comment: Thx for the answer, it did solve my problem! Just to make sure I got this correctly: Before writing any "delete X", I have to make sure that 'til that point I have written down/included everything that defines X, so all fields, methods, constructors, dependencies/headers, etc?

Comment: @MaXL130 the definition of the class before the delete is sufficient.

Comment: So basically including the header file of a class used in another class's destructor is mandatory?

Comment: @MaXL130 In short, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You should pay attention to compiler warning messages:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++      41120443.cpp    -o 41120443
41120443.cpp:1:15: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
 #include <set>;
               ^
41120443.cpp:7:7: warning: ‘class Room’ has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
 class Room {
       ^~~~
41120443.cpp:7:7: warning:   but does not override ‘Room(const Room&)’ [-Weffc++]
41120443.cpp:7:7: warning:   or ‘operator=(const Room&)’ [-Weffc++]
41120443.cpp: In constructor ‘Room::Room()’:
41120443.cpp:12:5: warning: ‘Room::door1’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
     Room(){}
     ^~~~
41120443.cpp:12:5: warning: ‘Room::door2’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
41120443.cpp: In destructor ‘Room::~Room()’:
41120443.cpp:15:16: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
         delete door1;
                ^~~~~
41120443.cpp:15:16: warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Door’
41120443.cpp:5:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Door’
 class Door; // Forward declaration
       ^~~~
41120443.cpp:15:16: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
         delete door1;
                ^~~~~
41120443.cpp:17:16: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
         delete door2;
                ^~~~~
41120443.cpp:17:16: warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Door’
41120443.cpp:5:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Door’
 class Door; // Forward declaration
       ^~~~
41120443.cpp:17:16: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
         delete door2;
                ^~~~~
41120443.cpp: At global scope:
41120443.cpp:22:7: warning: ‘class Door’ has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
 class Door {
       ^~~~
41120443.cpp:22:7: warning:   but does not override ‘Door(const Door&)’ [-Weffc++]
41120443.cpp:22:7: warning:   or ‘operator=(const Door&)’ [-Weffc++]
41120443.cpp: In constructor ‘Door::Door(Room*, Room*)’:
41120443.cpp:27:5: warning: ‘Door::roomA’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
     Door(Room* roomA, Room* roomB) {
     ^~~~
41120443.cpp:27:5: warning: ‘Door::roomB’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
41120443.cpp: In constructor ‘World::World()’:
41120443.cpp:56:5: warning: ‘World::rooms’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
     World() {
     ^~~~~
```

and Valgrind output:

```
valgrind  ./41120443 
==2864== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2864== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2864== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2864== Command: ./41120443
==2864== 
==2864== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2864==    at 0x4C2C291: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2864==    by 0x108BC3: Room::~Room() (41120443.cpp:17)
==2864==    by 0x108D67: World::~World() (41120443.cpp:68)
==2864==    by 0x108B65: main (41120443.cpp:75)
==2864== 
==2864== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2864==    at 0x4C2C291: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2864==    by 0x108BA8: Room::~Room() (41120443.cpp:15)
==2864==    by 0x108D67: World::~World() (41120443.cpp:68)
==2864==    by 0x108B65: main (41120443.cpp:75)
==2864== 
==2864== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2864==    at 0x4C2C2DB: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2864==    by 0x108BC3: Room::~Room() (41120443.cpp:17)
==2864==    by 0x108D67: World::~World() (41120443.cpp:68)
==2864==    by 0x108B65: main (41120443.cpp:75)
==2864==  Address 0x5a82e00 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==2864==    at 0x4C2C2DB: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2864==    by 0x108BA8: Room::~Room() (41120443.cpp:15)
==2864==    by 0x108D67: World::~World() (41120443.cpp:68)
==2864==    by 0x108B65: main (41120443.cpp:75)
==2864==  Block was alloc'd at
==2864==    at 0x4C2B21F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2864==    by 0x108CCE: World::World() (41120443.cpp:63)
==2864==    by 0x108B54: main (41120443.cpp:75)
```

You could make life much easier for yourself with judicious use of smart pointers:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

class Door; // Forward declaration

struct Room {
    std::shared_ptr<Door> door1 = {};
    std::shared_ptr<Door> door2 = {};

    ~Room();
};

struct Door {
    const std::weak_ptr<Room> roomA;
    const std::weak_ptr<Room> roomB;

    Door(std::shared_ptr<Room> roomA, std::shared_ptr<Room> roomB)
        : roomA(roomA),
          roomB(roomB)
    {
        roomA->door1 = roomB->door1 = std::shared_ptr<Door>{this};
    }

    ~Door() = default;
};

// Now that Door is complete, we can define ~Room
Room::~Room() = default;

struct World {
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Room>> rooms = {};

    World() {
        // Set up two rooms and link them using a door
        auto newRoom = std::make_shared<Room>();
        rooms.insert(newRoom);
        auto anotherNewRoom = std::make_shared<Room>();
        rooms.insert(anotherNewRoom);

        new Door(newRoom, anotherNewRoom);
    }

    ~World() = default;
};

int main() {

    World world;

    return 0;
}
```

This builds and runs cleanly:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++      41120443.cpp    -o 41120443
valgrind  ./41120443 
==3254== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3254== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3254== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3254== Command: ./41120443
==3254== 
==3254== 
==3254== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3254==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3254==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 72,952 bytes allocated
==3254== 
==3254== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3254== 
==3254== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3254== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for  helping me out, the smart-pointer example is going to help me a lot! I actually did not get any of the compiler messages above, I'll definitely check out Valgrind.

Comment: If you didn't get compilation errors/warnings, that's a likely sign that you're not adding enough `-W` options - so the first line for my usual set.  `-Wall` and `-Wextra` should be compulsory!

Answer (score 0):

You never delete the door

```
new Door(newRoom, anotherNewRoom);
```

You should add `Door *door` in world

```
public:
  Door *door;

...

  door = new Door(newRoom, anotherNewRoom);
```

and call delete in the destructor of world:

```
delete door;
```

note that your code has a lot of undefined behavior.

---

```
std::set<Room *> rooms;
```

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key.

You should use list:

```
std::list<Room *> rooms;
```

Comment: It can contain pointers as keys just fine. I agree that using another container will probably make more sense, but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @StoryTeller my bad, the question is confuse me. I add the answer.